# DataGridView control can't drag to my form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm hoping this is an overlook of a property by me, but I've searched `google` and can't seem to fix this issue. I went through the 'Add new data source' `wizard` and created a data source for my project. It's just a single table in a 'Service-Based-Database' I added to my project.

The tutorial I'm following says that you can use the `DataGridView` control to add to your form and easily manipulate data in my `table`, but when I try to just `drag` and `drop` the table directly from the Data Source Window nothing happens.

I can add a `DataGridView` control directly from my `toolbox` and connect to the `table` that way, but when I run program and try to edit data and close out the form, there's no 'save `button`' within the `DataGridView` like there is on the tutorial and I'm unsure how to add one without dragging it onto the form. I've checked my form '`AllowDrop`' property and that is set to True. Does anyone know why I'm unable to simply drag and drop directly from the data source window onto the `form`?

I would share code, but there isn't anything in my form code yet. I've read that when you drag and drop the `DataViewControl` to your form, Visual Studio auto-writes the method code in the `form`. [image]

Comment: what you want to do, you have to code for that.

Comment: Look this up for beginner's guide [How to Bind a BindingNavigator with a DataGridView in Windows Forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/how-to-bind-bindingnavigator-with-datagridview/)

Comment: All I want to do is drag my data source for my table onto my form so I can see the DataViewGrid control. When I drag it to the form, nothing happens. The form continues to be blank and have no controls listed.

Comment: What could possibly happen when you drag to the Form?? do you really expect a data-bound DGV to pop up? Why? Why not some other bindable control? You really need to work with that or others tutorials a little harder.